# Page redirecting to category (IE only)

Tags: categories, pages, redirect

I've got an odd problem...

I have a number of pages, all of which link to themselves correctly (as expected), however in IE, two of them link to a category page.

```
/ > /
/products > /category/blog
/applications > /applications
/customers > /category/blog
/technical > /technical
/distributors > /distributors
/about > /about
```

The offending products and customers pages also have sub-pages, which all link correctly, which is the same as the non-offending technical page.

If I rename the slug of products and customers, the pages behave correctly in IE.  As soon as I rename them back, they redirect to the category again.

Could it be that something is left behind in the database?  I know I did have a customers custom post type setup at some point, but I believe I removed the slugs correctly by de-registering the post-type (I think).  It's possible I also had a products post type at one point, but can't remember 100%.

If there any way of flushing / rebuilding all slugs etc, so any old or redundant slugs don't cause havoc with new ones?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have _categories_ named "products" or "customers"?

Comment: No, just news and blog